# Цвета наиболее благоприятны для использования в смартфонах при ярком солнце

Tags: цвета

Мне нужно подобрать цвета для мобильного приложения которое преимущественно будет использоваться на улице в том числе при ярком солнце.

Есть ли цвета которые при солнце видны лучше или хуже, к сожалению у меня солнце будет не скоро что бы протестировать?

Comment: Правильный ответ на этот вопрос -- нет, таких цветов нет, поскольку глянцевый ЖК-экран под солнцем будет белым под определёнными углами, и с этим ничего не сделать. А если на экране видно хоть что-нибудь, значит можно будет разобрать любые цвета, контрастные в любых других условиях.

Comment: Чёрный и белый?

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от качества экрана.

Comment: Ну вряд ли производитель ПО может это предусмотреть, берем что есть у всех разные экраны.

Comment: Ну тогда смотрите первый ответ.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/203125)

Comment: @AGS17 imho, этот ответ содержит решение вопроса. все действительно зависит от качества и от технологии изготовления экрана.

Comment: Мне кажется, стоило бы дать краткую характеристку самым распространённым типам экранов. И если есть какие-либо способы оптимизации, хотя бы упомянуть о них.

Comment: @PashaPash но согласитесь, это больше комментарий, нежели ответ. Человек спросил про цвета и получил "Все зависит от качества экрана". mymedia правильно сказал, надо было хотя бы привести примеры какие "качества экранов" существуют и дать хоть какие-то советы по цветовым схемам для этих экранов.

Comment: @PashaPash все равно что на вопрос "Как мне отсортировать массив" ответить "Смотря каким способом вы хотите", вместо предоставления вариантов сортировок и их хоть каких-нибудь реализаций.

Comment: Человек не в теме цветов,  экранов и прочего,  отсюда и вопрос может казаться дилетантским,  но развернутые ответы приветствуются.  Ответ в стиле зависит от качества экрана очевиден сам по себе.